# add table item with the value of invisible column

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have three container properties for `TreeTable`.

```
addContainerProperty("caption", String.class, null);
addContainerProperty("value", String.class, null);
addContainerProperty("deleted_flag", boolean.class, false);

setVisibleColumns("fields", "ids");
```

One of them should contain value - but don't want to display it all so I set visibile columns only to first two properties. Yet I want to have a value for the last property.

Whe I add item to the table like this

```
Object itemId = addItem(new Object[]{caption, value, isDeleted}, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

It returns `itemId` as `null`. If I add item like this

```
addItem(new String[]{caption, value}, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
```

it works ok and return `UUID`.

What is the problem? As far as I understand it is due to `addItem` method that expects only visibile values in the array. Then how to set the invisible value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it can be done like this

First I changed property type from primitive to object

```
addContainerProperty("deleted_flag", Boolean.class, false);
```

Then after adding item I get item and set property value

```
Object id = addItem(new Object[]{caption, value}, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
getItem(id).getItemProperty("deleted_flag").setValue(isDeleted);
```